# Program runs faster when dragged

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, qt

I am capturing the frames of a camera and displaying them as they come using Qt and C++. The frame rate of the video being shown was kinda slow (the camera was sending in 60fps but in the window the frames were really laggy) but when I just drag the window the frame rate jumps up becoming pretty fast.

Does windows or Qt promotes a thread to higher priority once it detects a drag to make the window update faster as the user drags the window, so the user wont see any lags?

Comment: This sounds like your GUI loop is running on a limited frame rate. If you drag your window, redrawing is required making your frame rate going up. Notice that GUI applications usually try to draw as little as possible.

Comment: You should have your video capture happening in a separate thread and use a timer to redraw your window.  When the timer fires, just draw the most recently captured frames.  This means your video will appear live, even though the UI might not be able to keep up with the frame rate.

Comment: @paddy do you know the Qt command to redraw the UI?

Comment: I'm unclear on the details, but I believe that under some circumstances Windows simply ignores (part of?) what the program is drawing to a window that is being dragged.  So it's possible that the apparently higher frame rate isn't real.

Comment: Maybe that is it...but hard to test it...